# How to use tableau-api with tableau server which uses live data from sql database

Tags: reactjs, charts, tableau-api

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';  
import tableau from 'tableau-api';  


class App extends Component {  
  componentDidMount() {  
    this.initViz()  
  }  


  initViz() {  
    const vizUrl = 'http://public.tableau.com/views/RegionalSampleWorkbook/Storms';  
    const vizContainer = this.vizContainer;  
    let viz = new window.tableau.Viz(vizContainer, vizUrl)  
  }  


  render() {  
    return (  
      <div ref={(div) => { this.vizContainer = div }}>  
      </div>  
    )  
  }  
}  


export default App;
```

[image: public tableau]

it works when i publish my workbook to public tableau with extract data source

but when i publish the same in tableau with live data source(sql),

[image: tableau dashboard]
I  obtained a url,

**https:///#/site/testsite/views/genderanalysis/Sheet2?:iid=1**

and that when i used here not working

and from the doc, i found  api with unique-token
**https:// /trusted/%3CTRUSTED%20TICKET%20HERE%3E/t/testsite/views/genderanalysis/Sheet2?:embed=yes&:comments=no&:toolbar=yes&:refresh=yes&:embed=y&:showVizHome=n&:jsdebug=y&:bootstrapWhenNotified=y&:apiID=handler0**

But i dont know how to generate unique-token

when i browse it on a website it shows token error

[image: token error on browser]

i used **https:///trusted/** with username as param, but it always returns **-1**

im using trial version

Did this worked for anyone?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use [Trusted Authentication](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth.htm) but haven't done the steps necessary to create and use tokens. First, you need to [configure Tableau Server](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth_trustIP.htm) to accept and trust requests from the server you will be embedding the dashboards in. Once you've done that you will be able to [make POST requests for tokens](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth_webrequ.htm) from your web server. That is the time you use the `username` and other parameters. You will then receive a token that you can use to construct the URL for the view. Hope this helps!